# Detect Fingerprint Reader Input outside of Console App

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-8, msmq, biometrics

So I need to make a Metro GUI App that uses an external fingerprint reader for user identification.

I've come so far as to make a DLL in C++ so I can call a method I made called `CaptureSample()` in C# referencing that DLL. The `CaptureSample()` method provides me with a byte array that represents the scanned fingerprint (a greyscale image from the fingerprint reader). So good so far. The way it does this, is to use the Microsoft Biometrics Framework to access the reader, wait for the reader to detect that a finger was laid on top of it, then send the data back of the scanned fingerprint.

This all works great. There is one catch however: **I HAVE to run whatever application I am making as Administrator to make use of the framework.** This is also why I can't just run the framework from the Webservice because the Webservice is run as a Network User or similar, making the library deny any access when tried to using it. So I have to make an extra console program that can run it instead.

Now here is where things get hairy. In order to make the fingerprint reader work with a Windows Metro GUI App, you'd have to run the app as admin. This is not possible as all Metro GUI apps run in a sandbox. I have to make an external console application that calls the DLL functionality for the app and then send the result of that back to the app.

To make things even more complicated I've found out that the Windows Phone subset of .NET does not have MSMQ which would have been nice to use. So instead, I made a local WCF Service that the Metro app needs to call, then the WCF Service calls the console program via MSMQ and sends the info back to the Metro GUI App whenever it receives it from the Console app.

So far so good. In theory. I've run into a problem in this process because the Console Application does run and is ready to scan when asked. But when I scan my finger nothing happens. The console needs focus in order to work, and that's out of the question as the app runs like a Kiosk and should never leave the Metro GUI App at all unless for maintenance.

I've looked at various solutions for detecting keyboard input outside a C# application but I don't think that applies to a Fingerprint Reader or if it does, I don't know how I'd do that. Any suggestions?

Just for good meassure I included a workflow chart so it's easier to understand. (It's a P5100 Zvetcobiometrics Fingerprint Reader, if anyone is curious):

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why the console app would need focus to work. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Also, taking a step back just to make sure: You state "the Webservice is run as a Network User or similar" - is this an unchangeable fact because of external restrictions? How do you host it anyway? For example, could you use a Windows Service running under an identity with elevated privileges?

Comment: @nodots Great Questions! I'll answer the Webservice Question first: If you run the WCF Service on the tablet (which I do), it will be run as either NETWORK or another Local Service account that isn't the users account. This is unchangeable because of Microsoft. When you try to do this the Windows Biometrics Framework will reject the read request and give you an Access Denied Exception. About the console: Since the Reader is registered as a HID unit it won't trigger any events when you try to read a fingerprint unless the application calling the read is in focus.

Comment: Re console focus: Ah ok, got it now. / Re service: How exactly do you host the WCF service (IIS, Windows Service, self-hosted, ...)? I still don't see why you shouldn't be able - for example - to create a Windows Service as host and run it under a different identity (services.msc -> right click -> Properties -> Log on).

Comment: It's run via IIS locally on the tablet and I am unable to change the user on that service.

Comment: In IIS you can create a new application pool, assign a different identity, and have your WCF service application use this app pool.

Comment: Maybe, I am missing something here but why do you "HAVE to run whatever application I am making as Administrator to make use of the framework"? To me it seems like this is where things take a turn for the worst introducing an enormous amount of potentially unnecessary complexity.

Comment: @Randy This is due to how Microsoft set up the Windows Biometrics Framework. You cannot run an application that uses this framework without running it as administrator. It's detailed in the documentation about the framework on Microsoft's own pages.

Comment: That's seems really odd. That implies that only administrators can authenticate with a fingerprint reader. Can you point me to the documentation for this?

Comment: @Randy Sure, here you go *"To call this function successfully, you must open the session handle by specifying WINBIO_FLAG_RAW in the Flags parameter of the WinBioOpenSession or WinBioAsyncOpenSession functions. Currently, only applications running under the Administrators and Local System accounts have the necessary privileges."* https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd401603(v=vs.85).aspx it's the first paragraph under "Remarks".

Comment: Okay, reading through the documentation a bit more and I see that only certain types of call require admin access. Any reason why you need to use WINBIO_FLAG_RAW?

Comment: @Randy We use SourceAFIS to run Enrollment and Identification on the fingerprints we scan, which works with Raw Images.

Comment: Is it safe to assume you have full control over the devices you are deploying to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I ran across an issue like this with Windows Forms, but not exactly with the issues that you described.

I understand that my solution isn't a pre-coded easy-day solution for you but I feel that with some minor modifications, an obstacle I overcame a few years ago may be of use to you. If you think my solution may help you, I can send you any missing pieces.

I created an inventory management system that utilized barcode scanners and I decided to implement the capability of being able to handle the input from a device by marshalling in some C++ classes without requiring the use of an input control such as a textbox. I needed the application to be able to process barcode input and make decisions without any additional user interactions or requirements. Just scan and go. The immediate use of the input from a keyboard/HID device is why I feel that this solution fits your question.

While testing the application I wrote, I was able to be inside of a full-screen game and still was able to utilize the barcode scanner as expected in the windows forms inventory application. This same functionality should work just as well in a console environment as console applications don't stop when they're in the background. You can even set it as NT AUTHORITY and prevent it from displaying to the desktop while running as a service and it should still chug away.

What I did was I used the Win32API to reflect through the devices, matched the device with the device specified via the application (User-chosen) and basically established a listener for that specific device.

You could use your console application to trigger the fingerprint sensor by running the console application as the local service account or programmatically obtaining necessary authorization (which would allow you to run it in elevated permissions without the UAC stuff getting in your way) and then use this inside of your metro app to read the input from the device as the device sends it.

Below are some of the code files for going about what I describe and have been modified to be specific towards my barcode scanner functionality.

Again, please contact me privately if you'd like to see any missing pieces.

PS: This technically could be used as a hack for intercepting keys and the sort so I will put a disclaimer for you to use at your own discretion and I am not responsible for anything that someone stupid may do with this code.

BarcodeScannerListenerInteropHelper.h:

```
#include <winuser.h>

BEGIN_INTEROP_NAMESPACE

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace HFSLIB::Barcode;
using namespace HFSLIB::Barcode::Interop;
using namespace HFSLIB::Barcode::Infrastructure::BarcodeScannerListener;

/// <summary>
/// Provides some helper methods that help the BarcodeScannerListener use native
/// Windows APIs without resorting to P/Invoking from C#.
/// </summary>
public ref class BarcodeScannerListenerInteropHelper
{
    public:
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a dictionary of barcode device handles to information about
        /// the device.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hardwareIds">The enumerable of hardware IDs to filter by.</param>
        /// <returns>The device handle-to-information mapping of the filtered hardware IDs.</returns>
        Dictionary<IntPtr, BarcodeScannerDeviceInfo^>^ InitializeBarcodeScannerDeviceHandles(
            IEnumerable<String^>^ hardwareIds);

        /// <summary>
        /// Registers ourselves to listen to raw input from keyboard-like devices.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hwnd">the handle of the form that will receive the raw
        /// input messages</param>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">if the call to register with the
        /// raw input API fails for some reason</exception>
        void HookRawInput(IntPtr hwnd);

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets information from a WM_INPUT message.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rawInputHeader">The LParam from the WM_INPUT message.</param>
        /// <param name="deviceHandle">[Out] The device handle that the message came from.</param>
        /// <param name="handled">[Out] True if the message represents a keystroke from that device.</param>
        /// <param name="buffer">[Out] If handled is true, this contains the characters that the keystroke represents.</param>
        void GetRawInputInfo(
            IntPtr rawInputHeader, 
            IntPtr% deviceHandle, 
            bool% handled,
            String^% buffer);
    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Converts a native raw input type into our version.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rawInputType">The raw input type.</param>
        /// <returns>Our version of the type.</returns>
        static BarcodeScannerDeviceType GetBarcodeScannerDeviceType(DWORD rawInputType);
};

END_INTEROP_NAMESPACE
```

BarcodeScannerListenerInteropHelper.cpp:

```
#include "BarcodeScannerListenerInteropHelper.h"
using namespace System::ComponentModel;

BEGIN_INTEROP_NAMESPACE

/// <summary>
/// Gets information from a WM_INPUT message.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="rawInputHeader">The LParam from the WM_INPUT message.</param>
/// <param name="deviceHandle">[Out] The device handle that the message came from.</param>
/// <param name="handled">[Out] True if the message represents a keystroke from that device.</param>
/// <param name="buffer">[Out] If handled is true, this contains the characters that the keystroke represents.</param>
void BarcodeScannerListenerInteropHelper::GetRawInputInfo(
    IntPtr rawInputHeader,
    IntPtr% deviceHandle, 
    bool% handled,
    String^% buffer)
{
    UINT cbSize;
    HRAWINPUT hRawInput;

    hRawInput = (HRAWINPUT)rawInputHeader.ToPointer();
    if (GetRawInputData(hRawInput, RID_INPUT, NULL, &cbSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)) == 0)
    {
        RAWINPUT* raw;

        raw = (RAWINPUT*)malloc(cbSize);

        if (GetRawInputData(hRawInput, RID_INPUT, raw, &cbSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)) == cbSize)
        {
            deviceHandle = IntPtr(raw->header.hDevice);
            handled = raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD &&
                raw->data.keyboard.Message == WM_KEYDOWN;

            if (handled)
            {
                BYTE state[256];

                // Force the keyboard status cache to update
                GetKeyState(0);

                // Note: GetKeyboardState only returns valid state when
                // the application has focus -- this is why we weren't
                // getting shift keys when the application was not focused
                if (GetKeyboardState(state))
                {
                    WCHAR unmanagedBuffer[64];

                    if (ToUnicode(raw->data.keyboard.VKey,
                            raw->data.keyboard.MakeCode,
                            state,
                            unmanagedBuffer,
                            64,
                            0) > 0)
                    {
                        buffer = gcnew String(unmanagedBuffer);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        free(raw);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Registers ourselves to listen to raw input from keyboard-like devices.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="hwnd">the handle of the form that will receive the raw
/// input messages</param>
/// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">if the call to register with the
/// raw input API fails for some reason</exception>
void BarcodeScannerListenerInteropHelper::HookRawInput(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    RAWINPUTDEVICE rid[1];

    rid[0].dwFlags = 0;
    rid[0].hwndTarget = (HWND)hwnd.ToPointer();
    rid[0].usUsage = 0x06;     // Keyboard Usage ID
    rid[0].usUsagePage = 0x01; // USB HID Generic Desktop Page

    if (!RegisterRawInputDevices(rid, 1, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICE)))
    {
        InvalidOperationException^ e;

        e = gcnew InvalidOperationException(
            "The barcode scanner listener could not register for raw input devices.",
            gcnew Win32Exception());
        throw e;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns a dictionary of barcode device handles to information about
/// the device.
/// </summary>
Dictionary<IntPtr, BarcodeScannerDeviceInfo^>^ BarcodeScannerListenerInteropHelper::InitializeBarcodeScannerDeviceHandles(IEnumerable<String^>^ hardwareIds)
{
    Dictionary<IntPtr, BarcodeScannerDeviceInfo^>^ devices;
    UINT uiNumDevices;
    UINT cbSize;

    devices = gcnew Dictionary<IntPtr, BarcodeScannerDeviceInfo^>();
    uiNumDevices = 0;
    cbSize = sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST);

    if (GetRawInputDeviceList(NULL, &uiNumDevices, cbSize) != -1)
    {
        PRAWINPUTDEVICELIST pRawInputDeviceList;

        if (pRawInputDeviceList = (PRAWINPUTDEVICELIST)malloc(cbSize * uiNumDevices))
        {
            if (GetRawInputDeviceList(pRawInputDeviceList, &uiNumDevices, cbSize) != -1)
            {
                for (UINT i = 0; i < uiNumDevices; ++i)
                {
                    UINT pcbSize;
                    RAWINPUTDEVICELIST rid;

                    rid = pRawInputDeviceList[i];

                    if (GetRawInputDeviceInfo(rid.hDevice, RIDI_DEVICENAME, NULL, &pcbSize) >= 0 &&
                        pcbSize > 0)
                    {
                        WCHAR* deviceName;

                        deviceName = (WCHAR*)malloc(sizeof(WCHAR) * (pcbSize + 1));
                        if (GetRawInputDeviceInfo(rid.hDevice, RIDI_DEVICENAME, deviceName, &pcbSize) >= 0)
                        {
                            bool add;
                            IntPtr deviceHandle;
                            BarcodeScannerDeviceInfo^ info;
                            String^ managedDeviceName;

                            add = false;
                            deviceHandle = IntPtr(rid.hDevice);
                            managedDeviceName = gcnew String(deviceName);

                            for each (String^ hardwareId in hardwareIds)
                            {
                                if (managedDeviceName->IndexOf(hardwareId, StringComparison::OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                                {
                                    add = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            if (add)
                            {
                                info = gcnew BarcodeScannerDeviceInfo(
                                    managedDeviceName,
                                    BarcodeScannerListenerInteropHelper::GetBarcodeScannerDeviceType(rid.dwType),
                                    deviceHandle);

                                devices->Add(deviceHandle, info);
                            }
                        }

                        free(deviceName);
                    }
                }
            }

            free(pRawInputDeviceList);
        }
    }

    return devices;
}

/// <summary>
/// Converts a native raw input type into our version.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="rawInputType">The raw input type.</param>
/// <returns>Our version of the type.</returns>
BarcodeScannerDeviceType BarcodeScannerListenerInteropHelper::GetBarcodeScannerDeviceType(DWORD rawInputType)
{
    BarcodeScannerDeviceType type;

    switch (rawInputType)
    {
        case RIM_TYPEHID:
            type = BarcodeScannerDeviceType::HumanInterfaceDevice;
            break;
        case RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD:
            type = BarcodeScannerDeviceType::Keyboard;
            break;
        default:
            type = BarcodeScannerDeviceType::Unknown;
            break;
    }

    return type;
}

END_INTEROP_NAMESPACE
```

BarcodeScannerListener.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using HFSLIB.Barcode.Infrastructure.BarcodeScannerListener;
using HFSLIB.Barcode.Interop;

namespace HFSLIB.Barcode
{
/// <summary>
/// This class uses Windows's native Raw Input API to listen for input from
/// a certain set of barcode scanners and devices. This way, the application
/// can receive input from a barcode scanner without the user having to
/// worry about whether or not a certain text field has focus, which was a
/// big problem
/// </summary>
public class BarcodeScannerListener : NativeWindow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A mapping of device handles to information about the barcode scanner
    /// devices.
    /// </summary>
    private Dictionary<IntPtr, BarcodeScannerDeviceInfo> devices;

    /// <summary>
    /// The WM_KEYDOWN filter.
    /// </summary>
    private BarcodeScannerKeyDownMessageFilter filter;

    /// <summary>
    /// The barcode currently being read.
    /// </summary>
    private StringBuilder keystrokeBuffer;

    /// <summary>
    /// The interop helper.
    /// </summary>
    private BarcodeScannerListenerInteropHelper interopHelper =
        new BarcodeScannerListenerInteropHelper();

    /// <summary>
    /// Event fired when a barcode is scanned.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler BarcodeScanned;

    /// <summary>
    /// Attaches the listener to the given form.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="form">The form to attach to.</param>
    public void Attach(Form form)
    {
        IntPtr hwnd;

        if (form == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("form");
        }

        hwnd = form.Handle;

        this.keystrokeBuffer = new StringBuilder();

        this.InitializeBarcodeScannerDeviceHandles();
        this.interopHelper.HookRawInput(hwnd);
        this.HookHandleEvents(form);

        this.AssignHandle(hwnd);

        this.filter = new BarcodeScannerKeyDownMessageFilter();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this.filter);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Hook into the form's WndProc message. We listen for WM_INPUT and do
    /// special processing on the raw data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="m">the message</param>
    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case NativeMethods.WM_INPUT:
                if (this.ProcessRawInputMessage(m.LParam))
                {
                    this.filter.FilterNext = true;
                }

                break;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Fires the barcode scanned event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="deviceInfo">information about the device that generated
    /// the barcode</param>
    private void FireBarcodeScanned(BarcodeScannerDeviceInfo deviceInfo)
    {
        string barcode;
        EventHandler handler;

        barcode = this.keystrokeBuffer.ToString();

        if (barcode != null && barcode.Length > 0)
        {
            handler = this.BarcodeScanned;

            this.keystrokeBuffer = new StringBuilder();

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new BarcodeScannedEventArgs(barcode, deviceInfo));
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Hooks into the form's HandleCreated and HandleDestoryed events
    /// to ensure that we start and stop listening at appropriate times.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="form">the form to listen to</param>
    private void HookHandleEvents(Form form)
    {
        form.HandleCreated += this.OnHandleCreated;
        form.HandleDestroyed += this.OnHandleDestroyed;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the barcode scanner device handles.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeBarcodeScannerDeviceHandles()
    {
        BarcodeScannerListenerConfigurationSection config;
        BarcodeScannerListenerConfigurationElementCollection hardwareIdsConfig;
        IEnumerable<string> hardwareIds;

        config = BarcodeScannerListenerConfigurationSection.GetConfiguration();
        hardwareIdsConfig = config.HardwareIds;
        hardwareIds = from hardwareIdConfig in hardwareIdsConfig.Cast<BarcodeScannerListenerConfigurationElement>()
                      select hardwareIdConfig.Id;

        this.devices = this.interopHelper.InitializeBarcodeScannerDeviceHandles(hardwareIds);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When the form's handle is created, let's hook into it so we can see
    /// the WM_INPUT event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">the form whose handle was created</param>
    /// <param name="e">the event arguments</param>
    private void OnHandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.AssignHandle(((Form)sender).Handle);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When the form's handle is destroyed, let's unhook from it so we stop
    /// listening and allow the OS to free up its resources.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">the form whose handle was destroyed</param>
    /// <param name="e">the event arguments</param>
    private void OnHandleDestroyed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ReleaseHandle();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Process the given WM_INPUT message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rawInputHeader">the rawInputHeader of the message</param>
    /// <returns>whether or not the keystroke was handled</returns>
    private bool ProcessRawInputMessage(IntPtr rawInputHeader)
    {
        BarcodeScannerDeviceInfo deviceInfo;
        bool handled;
        bool keystroke;
        string localBuffer;
        IntPtr rawInputDeviceHandle;

        handled = false;
        keystroke = false;
        localBuffer = string.Empty;
        rawInputDeviceHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

        this.interopHelper.GetRawInputInfo(
            rawInputHeader,
            ref rawInputDeviceHandle,
            ref keystroke,
            ref localBuffer);

        if (this.devices.TryGetValue(rawInputDeviceHandle, out deviceInfo) && keystroke)
        {
            handled = true;

            if (localBuffer.Length == 1 && localBuffer[0] == 0xA)
            {
                this.FireBarcodeScanned(deviceInfo);
            }
            else
            {
                this.keystrokeBuffer.Append(localBuffer);
            }
        }

        return handled;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: So in the end, me and a colleague decided to port it all from the Metro App to a Desktop WPF app that looks exactly the same but gives us the entire library of .NET. However, after looking through your solution and trying to apply it, I could definitively see this be a solution to the problem if you just modify it enough to read a fingerprint reader instead of a barcode reader. Thanks for sharing, and grats on the points!

Comment: Awesome! That's outstanding news! If you would like to persue those modifications and such, I'd be more than happy to share the remaining pieces and show you how I implemented it.